# Windows Store App minidump crash debug issue with windbg

Tags: c#, debugging, crash, windows-store-apps, windbg

I submitted an update of my app to the windows store and it failed certification because of crash.
I received a triagedump.dmp file from them.

I opened the file with windbg and loaded sos and mscordacwks dll's and typed !analyze -v

I got

MANAGED_OBJECT_NAME:  SYSTEM.NULLREFERENCEEXCEPTION

MANAGED_STACK_COMMAND:  !pe 2931590

```
So i did !pe 2931590

Exception object: 02931590
Exception type:   System.NullReferenceException
Message:          <Invalid Object>
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    050CE81C 6E653202 YoutubeMP3Converter_ni!UNKNOWN+0x9a
    050CF58C 6F1DE6FF mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(System.Object)+0x33
    050CF594 6CA313D4 System_Runtime_WindowsRuntime_ni!UNKNOWN+0x24
    0A43F964 6F0E2607 mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()+0x17
    0A43F96C 6CA5E728 System_Runtime_WindowsRuntime_ni!UNKNOWN+0x28
    0A43F970 6E9ECB6A mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)+0x3e
    0A43F978 6EA02407 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+0xa7
    0A43F9E4 6EA02346 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+0x16
    0A43F9F8 6EA0DE60 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()+0x60
    0A43FA0C 6EA0D609 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()+0x149
    0A43FA5C 6EA0D4A5 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()+0x5
```

I don't know the UNKNOWN part of YoutubeMP3Converter_ni!UNKNOWN+0x9a
So i don't have the YoutubeMP3Converter.ni.exe file they used.
I also tried to use my YoutubeMP3Converter.exe but he said that there is a mismatch with the memory image header en the file image header.

**So what are my options here?**
- Can I create the .ni (native image) version of my exe.
- How can I get the correct YoutubeMP3Converter.exe? Do I have to take it out the appxupload package?
- Can I create my windows store app with options if it crashes that it creates a full dump instead of a triagedump (minidump) ?

I know what the exception is but I don't know where it happens as I don't have the full stacktrace :(.

- UPDATE - found it
  You can find the matching .exe to load as img in windbg in AppxUpload package which is send when you upload your app to the store. Then WinDbg has enough info to show the correct symbols which will lead you to what class/method the exception was thrown.

Comment: `!U 6E653202` will show you an annotated disassembly of the managed method at the top of the stack but since this is not a full dump it might not. If it does, then the annotations may provide a clue as to what the actual managed method is.

Comment: Hmm sadly i get :
HResult: 80004003
0:022> !U 6E653202
Unmanaged code
6e653202 ??              ???
6e653203 ??              ???
6e653204 ??              ???
6e653205 ??              ???
6e653206 ??              ???
6e653207 ??              ???
6e653208 ??              ???
6e653209 ??              ???
6e65320a ??              ???
6e65320b ??              ???

Comment: Found it, i took the exe out of the appxupload package and was able to load the symbols and knew method and class and now I fixed the bug.